# React: unique "key" prop does not apply to table rows?

Tags: reactjs, key, tablerow, listitem

React uses key prop to identify elements and reconcile properly. The following code will give console warnings `Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop`.

```
const List = () => 
  <ul>
    {[...Array(3)].map((_, idx) => <li>{idx}</li>)}
  </ul>
```

While this won't

```
const Table = () => 
  <table>
    <tbody>
      {[...Array(3)].map((_, idx) => <tr><td>{idx}</td></tr>)}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Why is unique key prop not required when using table row?

Answer (score 0):

Uniq key is require for every child in an array or iterator, so you probably checking wrong. For react is no matter type of html tag.

```
// react.development.js
function validateChildKeys(node, parentType) {
  if (typeof node !== 'object') {
    return;
  }
  if (Array.isArray(node)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
      var child = node[i];
      if (isValidElement(child)) {
        validateExplicitKey(child, parentType);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think it's kinda obvious that `{[...Array(3)].map((_, idx) => <tr><td>{idx}</td></tr>)}` returns an array.